# AQuery AJAX caching

Tags: java, android, ajax, aquery

How to get Android AQuery to download data from the Internet, if possible, otherwise - from the cache ???
My code:

```
final GetFeedsAjaxCallback ac = new GetFeedsAjaxCallback(...);
aq.ajax(feed, XmlDom.class, -1, ac);
```

My code does not work if there is no internet connection.

Comment: Äh what?!? :-) Ajax in Java?!? Is that a framework I don't know? Or is there a special reason not to use AsyncTask?

Comment: @Neo , https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI

Answer (score 0):

use code:

```
    AQuery aq;
    //...
    final GetFeedsAjaxCallback ac = new GetFeedsAjaxCallback(...);
    aq.ajax(feed, XmlDom.class, -1, ac);
```

...

```
if (status.getCode() != 200 || xml == null)
try {
     xml = new com.androidquery.util.XmlDom(new FileInputStream(aq.getCachedFile(url)));
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
 //do something
```